# How to get AdTags for Google IMA SDK android

Tags: google-dfp, google-ima, preroll

I have created a mobile application, I want to show Google IMA ads in my app with my Exoplayer. We have created a sample application to show IMA ads in Exoplayer using sample tags provided by this url : https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/tags. I want to get video ads from Google. So i have created an account in DoubleClick for Publishers. How can i generate adtags to get preroll,midroll,postroll ads in my Exoplayer.

Answer (score 1):

To get preroll, midroll, and postroll ads you might want to look into [Ad Rules](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1406475?hl=en) offered by DoubleClick. You will be able to generate tags once you have specified tracking URLs, and uploaded your mediafiles to the DFP UI.